# Error:(63, 34) fatal error: machine/cpu-features.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, telegram, ubuntu-17.10

i want to compile telegram source code but i got this error

```
Error:(63, 34) fatal error: machine/cpu-features.h: No such file or directory
```

my environment:
ubuntu 64 bit 17.10

**Update:**

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./jni/libwebp/src
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
....
....
$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

the libjpeg library that has the class armv6_idct.s

```
    #ifdef __arm__
    #include <machine/cpu-features.h>
    #endif
```

ndk version:16.1.4479499

how can i solve this error???

**finally i got the cause of problem:**
The new version of the ndk was due to this problem.

Comment: Well, is there one?

Comment: Yes, Only this is an error.

Comment: Doesn't look like a fully-specified path to me.  Your include paths correct for where you're compiling?

Comment: updated the question. Could I guide?